# Is it possible to merge 2 rows in 1 in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I need to merge multiple rows(2 rows in 1 base on conditions) in my table in one, base on:

> same custid and same appdate and price = paid

and have the desire output.

My data now:

```
tbla
appid   custid    appdate    price   paid
1         1       10/10/20     20    null
2         2       10/10/20     10    null
3         1       11/10/20     30    null
4         3       12/10/20     20    null
5         1       13/10/20     20    null
6         1       10/10/20    null    20
7         2       11/10/20    null    10
8         1       11/10/20    null    20
9         3       12/10/20    null    20
10        1       13/10/20    null    20
```

Derire output:

```
tblb
appid   custid    appdate    price    paid
1         1       10/10/20     20       20     => same custid, same appdate, price=paid
2         2       10/10/20     10     null     
3         1       11/10/20     30     null     
4         3       12/10/20     20       20     => same custid, same appdate, price=paid
5         1       13/10/20     20       20     => same custid, same appdate, price=paid
7         2       11/10/20   null       10     
8         1       11/10/20   null       20
```

Don't bother with appid.I am going to rebuild appid in the end, by creating a new fresh table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation with a twist:

```
select min(appid) as appid, custid, appdate,
       max(price) as price, max(paid) as paid
from tbla
group by custid, appdate, coalesce(price, paid);
```

The twist is treating the `price`/`paid` as a single column.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29a64bd68c699f82d408cd3f5443555c) is a db<>fiddle.

Note that in your sample data, one of `paid` or `price` is always `NULL`.  If there are exceptions, then this code might not work.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results if that is the case.

Comment: Found a bug. If i have two lines with same id,date, paid it count one `https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8d046b600fe16eb91ac555b7f6c3f02` So the total sum of all price and all paid will not end up like the original table.

Comment: @YvetteLee . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  I would suggest you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and explanation of what you want to do in the situation that you describe in the comment.  The results from this query are consistent with your existing question (even if that is not what you really want).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like simple aggregation does what you want:

```
select min(appid) as appid, custid, appdate, sum(price) as price, sum(paid) as paid
from mytable
group by custid, appdate
```

Comment: The table has 15K rows. Some have data like appid 1-5 and some like 6-10. It doesn't have to do with min and sum. Please check the output table. And THANK you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` with `union`:

```
with r as 
  (select t2.appid t2app, t1.appid, t1.custid, t1.appdate, t1.price, t2.paid from test t1 join test t2 on t1.custid = t2.custid and t1.appdate = t2.appdate and t1.price = t2.paid)
select r.appid, r.custid, r.appdate, r.price, r.paid from r
union
select * from test where not exists (select 1 from r where r.t2app = test.appid) and not exists (select 1 from r where r.appid = test.appid);
```